# Handling muliple database using spring and hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, session, multi-tenant

We want to scale horizontally by pushing data to different database based on user groups. This is required since data would be huge. Right now we are looking at RDBMS only. Spring and hibernate/Eclipse-link is what options we have. I have few questions around it and I see similar questions have been asked multiple times. I am asking this again since I want to understand few more specifics.

What are the best practices one should follow when using multiple databases?(Detailed questions below)

1. Multiple session factories or single session factory? What is the recommended approach? I see lot of posts talking about creating multiple session factories and dynamic data source implementation uses single session factory and provides different data source based on user group. Any scalability issues using single session factory having many user groups?
2. All sessions are tied to session factories or the underlying data source? I am assuming that multiple connection pools would be created based on each db am I right?
3. Dynamic data source implementation of spring to handle multiple databases or Hibernate multi-tenancy?
4. Are their any issues with Transaction mgmt when it comes to using dynamic data source? I didn't see any posts except for 2nd level cache.
5. If used c3P0 for connection pooling how its handled in the case of dynamic data source approach?
6. Any Dos and donts for above approaches?

Answer (score 0):

There is a project developed by Hibernate people and Google, called [Hibernate Shards](http://hibernate.org/others/). It is there for just what you need, sharding data across multiple databases.

It provides interfaces named:

- org.hibernate.shards.session.ShardedSession
- org.hibernate.shards.ShardedSessionFactory
- org.hibernate.shards.criteria.ShardedCriteria
- org.hibernate.shards.query.ShardedQuery

Each one extends Hibernate's classic interface (with similar name!)

By using Hibernate Shards all multi-tenancy logic goes behind Hibernate, and most of the time you don't have to deal with it.

So transaction management remains, in your case, you shall have a distributed JTA transaction manager, and it would be much easier if you use an application server such as JBoss.

Comment: I am not sure how active this project is.Please see the link http://hibernate.org/others/